# Query about np.log in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This is probably a trivial question, but I've been struggling with it for a while. For some reason, when I used the line of code below I get the Error `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log print np.log(69/74)`. I can't figure out why this is the case.

```
np.log(69/74)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing integer division

```
>>> 69/74
0
```

As `float` you get

```
>>> 69.0/74.0
0.9324324324324325
```

Comment: For mathematical code in Python, I always put `from __future__ import division` at the top of my source file. This makes integer division return a floating point result by default.